# What is the work that had FTL travel but no FTL communications?

Tags: story-identification, ftl-drive

I remember reading a work (It was most likley a series of books though not 100% sure) that had a universe where there was technology for FTL spaceflight, but no FTL communications (excluding of course using FTL ship as a courier).

Can someone identify it?

<sub>I think it may have been Weber's Honor Harrington world but it's been a long while so I'm not remembering enough details</sub>

NOTE: One detail I remember is that at the end, some sort of FTL communication was jury-rigged or initially developed as the plot progressed, but it was limited range

Comment: There are multiples of those. The Empire of Man universe (*The Mote in God's Eye*, etc.) for one. *Dread Empire's Fall* for another. This situation is in no way unique in the literature.

Comment: More. Scalzi's *Old Man's War* universe, and while I don't believe it is ever stated Heinlein's Lazarus timeline seems to require this constraint. Halderman's *Forever War* universe (though there is FTL travel takes inconveniently long).

Comment: Without a *lot* more to go on this question is [everything that Jeff complained about](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) ID questions being.

Comment: This question is just too broad. Without more details to go on, then this could be any of at least a dozen universes... Thus, in it's current form it stands as more of a list question, so I closed it.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto Alright then.  Both DVK and I thought this was much more unique than it apparently is.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - Added extra detail that should make it a lot more restricted (and according to a provided answer matching it perfectly with my own guess of what I was remembering)

Comment: Another example: In Dan Simmons' "Endymion"/"Rise of Endymion", the disappearance of FTL communication (since the first 2 novels) and availability of FTL courier ships is a major plot point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Honorverse certainly fits the description - there is FTL spaceflight (riding gravity waves using Warshawski sails or wormholes - sublight travel uses a related gravitic drive called an impeller) but communication either inter- or intra-system is limited to lightspeed. And a similar restriction applies to some of the ship-to-ship weaponry using lasers and gamma ray lasers (grasers) - to paraphrase (since I can't remember the exact quote and I haven't got the books on my Kindle yet)

> grasers were a light-speed weapon - the first you knew you were being
>   attacked by one was when you got hit

There are FTL *sensors*, however, since gravity is ruled to propagate faster than the speed of light, allowing for the detection of ships using their impeller drives, and as the series of books progresses a crude FTL communication method develops for use in-system, using sensor drones equipped with gravity emitters; however the gravity emitters can only generate 'pulses' at a slow rate, and so the drones can only emit, at best, a kind of Morse code. The limited range (in an interstellar context) of gravitic sensors makes this impractical for use between systems.

This lack of inter-system communication (except by, as you say, FTL courier) becomes an important plot point in several of the books, for example in *The Honor of the Queen* where the only way to send for reinforcements is to despatch a courier to a neighbouring system and then hope the cavalry arrives in time...

Answer (score 2):

The *Traveller* RPG system features FTL travel through pocket dimensions inflated with hydrogen, this method of traveling precludes FTL communication, which forms the majority of the commerce: ferrying post around.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of linking to TV Tropes, this page (search for "Aversions With FTL Travel" section) has a healthy list: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SubspaceAnsible.

The one I immediately thought of was the settings for the Night's Dawn trilogy, but it could be any of the others.

Comment: does any of them satsfy the last paragraph?

Comment: Hmmm...maybe not. Sorry, missed that. The _Honor Harrington_ description sounds closest.