# Why use the Argus Array for spying?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In episode 11 of season 7 of TNG, the story takes place around the Argus Array, a subspace telescope reprogramed to observe several Federation sites: DS5, Starbase 47, the Iadara Colony, and the Utopia Planitia Shipyards.  The problem with using this to spy is that

- Argus to DS5 = 28 ly
- Argus to Starbase 47 = 17 ly
- Argus to Iadara Colony = 5 ly
- Argus to Utopia Planitia (Mars) = 71 ly

Why would a hostile race use a telescope that gives data at least 5 years old?

Comment: For the record, deciphering WWII communications (from 1944) revealed a spy operating in the 1980s. Old data is still very much useful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Argus Array](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Argus_Array) is a *subspace* telescope, capable of imaging far objects in near realtime. Its observations are not restricted to the speed of light.

> The Enterprise hovering in front of the ARGUS ARRAY. It is **a huge
> subspace radio telescope** -- a series of panels, resembling several
> very long box-kites stacked one on top of the other. It looks
> absolutely immense.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Nth Degree - Original Script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/193.txt)</sup></sub>

Taking into account [the speed at which messages can propagate through subspace](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120582/20774) (Warp 9.997 / 183,000 times the speed of light), the pictures would only be a few seconds out of date.